# Create Pattern on RGB Colors

Tags: javascript, css, apexcharts

I'm currently using [Apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/timeline-charts/multi-series/) to display a data series. In one of the options, I can select an array of colors as defined in the [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/colors/), which is an array of strings. Obviously, passing in hex strings works just fine.

However, what I'm trying to do now is to have my data series on my graph show with patterns. I understand that I can use the `fill` object as defined [here](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/fill/), but that would define a pattern for the whole graph, whereas I would like to define it for certain data only.

Since the `color` array is an array of strings, is there a way where I can define something like `linear-gradient` or something equivalent but in string format?

**EDIT:**

As an example, suppose I have [this data series](https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/timeline-charts/multi-series/) from the Apexchart website. Is there a way that I can set a condition, say if the person is 'Joe' and the type is 'test', then set the gradient to be something (for example `gradient: slantedLines`)?

The result would therefore be something like:
[image]

**EDIT2:**

I have also seen another question whereby we can specify the property `fillColor` to specify the color of a given bar [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160731/change-color-of-range-column-chart-in-apexcharts). Is there an equivalent to explicitly set the gradient?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and corresponding output?

Comment: Right off the top of my head, if you need gradually changing colors, you may define your colors using [`hsl()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl()) and pass in different `L` parameters.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov an example input would be `colors: ['#2E93fA', '#66DA26', '#546E7A', '#E91E63', '#FF9800']` and the output would be the corresponding colors for each RBG color. What I'd like is therefore to specify something that can give me a pattern (in string format) rather than a hex string.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thank you for your other suggestion. is `hsl()` a library I'd have to import or is it one that is built-in? I'm getting an error `cannot find name 'hsl'` if I use it directly.

Comment: By *'...output would be the corresponding color'*, you mean like `'#2E93fA'` should be translated to `'light blue'`?

Comment: In this example, yes. But for me, I'd like a color that contains a pattern of some sort, similar to what `linear-gradient' provides, as an example. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question needs some clarification, but this seems to be the most logical answer:

#### Part 1

> [In a multi-series chart, you can pass an array to allow a combination of fill types like this:](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/fill/#:%7E:text=In%20a%20multi,type%3A%20%5B%27solid%27%2C%20%27gradient%27%5D%0A%7D)
>
> ```
> fill: {
>   // All series use same type: gradient.
>   type: 'gradient'  
> }
> /* OR */
> fill: {
>   // Series alternate between solid type and gradient type.
>   type: ['solid', 'gradient']  
> }
> ```

#### Part 2

Then, if you want each gradient to use different colors, you pass them as arrays in `fill.colors` *and* `fill.gradient.gradientToColors` (You need two different arrays because gradients transition from a "start" color to a different "end" color.)

> [`gradientToColors: Array`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/fill/#:%7E:text=gradientToColors%3A%20Array,the%20series-index.)
>
> Optional colors that ends the gradient to. The main colors array
> becomes the gradientFromColors and this array becomes the end colors
> of the gradient. Each index in the array corresponds to the
> series-index.

The above is an explanation of how to specify:

1. A fill type (solid, gradient, pattern, image) for all values in each series. (The two series from the [linked example](https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/timeline-charts/multi-series/) are blue 'Bob' and green 'Joe'.)
2. When fill type is gradient: the start/end colors for each value in a series. (The three different values from blue series 'Bob' are '3 days', '3 days', and '5 days'.)

The question is ambiguous and may be asking for something else (which may not even be supported by ApexCharts.) If the above did not answer the question, I suggest adding a sample mock-up image of the desired chart output.

**Update:** How to change the pattern ('gradient' and 'pattern' are two different types of fills: `slantedLines` is a pattern, not a gradient.)

The following options causes the 2nd and 3rd values to use patterns (it does not repeat as I assumed).

```
...
...
fill: {
    type: ["solid", "pattern", "pattern"],
    pattern: {
        style: "slantedLines"
    }
}
...
...
```

[Modified code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-timeline-colors-forked-p930t?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:771-895):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my question as per your suggestion to include a sample output (image) of what I am trying to achieve. I have also added another edit based off what I've seen in a different post. Please let me know if this makes sense as I would like your help.

Comment: Also, in the example you shared (https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/bar-charts/patterned/), is it possible to have the whole data series be different patterns? For example, if I wanted 2008 to be all circles, 2009 to be all slantedLines, etc, rather than having a mix of patterns that is the same for each data series?

Comment: @Adam: It is possible to make the whole data series use the same pattern, but I think the nth value of each data series must match the pattern of the nth value in the other series. That is why I suggested you may be asking for something that Apex charts does not support. I updated my answer with code + modified sandbox.

Comment: Thank you again @Leftium. The only issue is that I've got a data series where there is grouping (like this example apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/bar-charts/patterned) and so are you saying that given my previous comment of making 2008 one pattern, then 2009 a different pattern etc, is that not possible with Apexcharts? Because with your example, you assume that there is only one bar per row, and therefore we can specify the patterns row by row, whereas in my case, I've got a grouping of multiple bars per row, as the linked example.

Comment: Further to the above, in the linked example, patterns for each row will always be the same for the nth data series. For example, 2008, 2009,  2010 etc have the same pattern for Marine Sprite, then the same pattern for Striking Calf etc. Whereas I'd like for 2008 to have its own pattern altogether, different to 2009 etc. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: @Adam: I understand what you are asking for. I don't think it is possible, so I gave you the closest thing that is possible (how to change patterns in a way that is supported). If you don't use an array for `fill.type` then the series will all have the same pattern. However, all series must have this pattern (they can be different colors, though).

Comment: Thank you @Leftium, that makes sense. Could you have a look at my second edit on my post? There was another property that I had seen for the colors when creating a data series and so I was wondering if there was something similar for a pattern. That might resolve this issue if there is a property like that that exists.

Comment: @Adam: Already saw it. As far as I can tell, what you are asking for is not supported.

Comment: Ok thank you @Leftium. If it's okay, I'll leave the answer unchecked for now just in case someone else has a different view. But if not, I will gladly accept your answer as correct. Thank you for your help!